# How to break text below to another layout in Android

Tags: android

I have layouts like this, but I cannot put it into a shape

That is the look I want from my layouts, the break text needs to be below of about

```
About: A car is good to go
So you need things to make it going
```

But this is the look I get, this is my layout code,

```
About: A car is good to go
       So you need things to make it going
```

This is my layout code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/five"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I change my layout so break text could be below my layout. Thank you

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"` from second TextView

Comment: Use a single TextView and set a Span to the first word to change its color.

Comment: @JacobusConradi it has nothing to do with margin left, there are two horizontal textviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/five"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

We need to put the whole text into this single TextView. We retrieve it and apply a span:

```
TextView t = findViewByid(R.id.text);
Spannable s = new SpannableString("About: car is good to go so you need things to make it going");
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
t.setText(s);
```

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Remove marginLeft attribute from TextView and set orientation to Vertical in the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/five"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

Comment: Marta, you look cute, but I want different results :)

Comment: You said you want one textview below the other... but ok ;)